# How convert data between long and wide format in datatable

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, shinydashboard

I want to get values of kpi's column and set these values to the header of new data table.In this app I want the admin creates the KPIs and let the user to populate the values in the second data table.

[image: First table]

So I want to have a table such as bellow:

[image: New Data Table]

server.r

```
GetTableMetadata <- function() {
   fields <- c(id = "Id", 
               name = "Name", 
               used_shiny = "Used Shiny", 
               r_num_years = "R Years")

   result <- list(fields = fields)
   return (result)
 }
    #display table in wide format
     output$viewresponses<-DT::renderDataTable({

      viewDF<-(as.data.frame(responses))
      viewDF %>% spread(GetTableMetadata()$fields$name,GetTableMetadata()$fields$used_shiny)[-1]
      })
```

The error that I got is:

```
Error : Invalid column specification
```

Comment: lookup `dcast`, you want to shift your data from long to wide

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly that I want. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Answer (score 0):

I have used library(tidyr) package to convert the long format to wide format

```
KPI <- c('cost','time','quality','time','time')
 measurements <- c(1, 2, 3,2,1)
kpi.data <- data.frame(KPI, measurements)
```

The kpi.data is as following (long format):

```
  KPI measurements
1    cost            1
2    time            2
3 quality            3
4    time            2
5    time            1
```

By using spread function from tidyr it long format will be convert to wide format

```
kpi.data %>% spread(KPI,measurements)
```